# accessing child attribute with one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many

I have models `Member`,`Loan` and `Interestamount`. `Loan` has `hasMany` relationship with `Interestamount`. I can't seem to access data from `Interestamount`.

I can show loan `id` and `Interestamount` in blade but can't sort out `Interestamount` for the given `Loan`.

**LoanController.php**

```php
public function loanInterest($criteria){
    //$loanData = Loan::all();
    $loanData =Loan::findOrFail($criteria);
    return view($this->_pagePath.'loan.loaninterest',compact('loanData'));
}
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::any('loaninterest/{criteria?}','LoanController@loanInterest')
    ->name('loaninterest');
```

**Loan.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Loan extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'amount',
        'interest',
        'status',
        'duration',
        'member_id',
        'loan_type_id',
        'interest_type_id',
        'loan_payment_type_id'
    ];

    // protected $appends = 'interest_amount

    public function getInterestAmountAttribute()
    {
        return ($this->amount)/100 * $this->interest;
    }

    public function interestamount()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InterestAmount::class,'loan_id','id');
    }
}
```

**InterestAmount.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class InterestAmount extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['interestamount'];

    public function loan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Loan::class,'loan_id','id');
    }
}
```

**loaninterest.blade.php**

```php
<tr>
    <td>{{$loanData->member->name}}</td>
    @foreach($loanData->interestamount() as $int)
        <td>{{$int->interestamount}} </td>
    @endforeach     
</tr>
```

**loan.blade.php**

```php
<a href="{{route('loaninterest', $loan->id) }}">Interest detail</a>
```

Comment: instead of `$loanData->interestamount()` us `$loanData->interestamount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$loanData->interestamount()` returns query builder instance instead of result of the query.

There are several ways to get the result from relationship function.

One of them is call `get()` function

**Exmaple**

```php
$loanData->interestamount()->get();
```

Another way is call the relationship function `not as a function but as a property`

**Example**

```php
$loanData->interestamount;
```

so in your blade files `@foreach()`

```php
@foreach($loanData->interestamount as $int)
    <td>{{$int->interestamount}} </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: then first of all check this `$loadData->interestamount`. delete the `@foreach()` for a while and write this `{{ $loanData->interestamount }}`

Comment: yes when i do this it only gives one of many "interestamount". i used **interestamount()->get()** and i gives all the "interestamout"

Comment: I think that' because of some confusion with `getInterestAmountAttribute`. To be honest, your relationship name is __NOT OK__. (It's not an error, but not a proper name) since it returns many interest amounts, you should name it as `interestAmounts()` (plural.) and don't forget to use camel case.

Comment: yes i realized it earlier. it was actually "interest_amount" which then caused problem as you mentioned with getInterestAmountAttribute. so i changed it to "interestamount". thanks anyway. i'll make changes and see.

Answer (score 1):

change your loaninterest to this

```
<td>{{$loanData->member->name}}</td>
  @foreach($loanData->interestamount as $int)
   <td>{{$int->interestamount}} </td>
  @endforeach     
</tr>
```

When we use `$loanData->interestamount()` it refers to a query builder but when we use `$loanData->interestamount` it returns the related collection same as `$loanData->interestamount()->get()`

Comment: i actually did as you mentioned initially  and it gives **Error Invalid argument supplied for foreach**

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the reason but i did this and it worked.

```
  <td>{{$loanData->member->name}}</td>
  @foreach($loanData->interestamount()->get() as $int)
 <td>{{$int->interestamount}} </td>
  @endforeach
```